# Jquery phone number masking in asp mvc4 unable to submit form......unless masking removed prior to submit?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, maskedinput

I have tried several jquery masking inputs for phone numbers on a page I have been working on.

Here they are. :

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

They both work really well as far as the masking itself is concerned.  My issue is that when I trigger a submission of the form via javascript/jquery, aka. :

```
$('form').submit();
```

It will not submit my form.  So, in turn I figured that I would just remove the masking prior to the submission occurring which actually works fairly well until validation comes into play.  Once you start testing validation, you no longer have masked input, and it just isn't a very pretty situation within the page.  What I am wondering is that someone else must have run into this situation and solved it previously.....I am pretty open to any ideas about how to solve this issue, as I am currently stumped.

I have read this question on stackoverflow regarding how jquery validation and the input masking jquery are conflicting possibly.  I am personally not using jquery.validate.js on my page, but it is included in my page as a file, master page kind of situation.  Anyways, hoping there is an idea out there.  I can't just remove it prior to submission, and I don't think I am understanding what is truly occurring in the below link even though I have read it several times.

[Conflict between jQuery Validate and Masked Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399086/conflict-between-jquery-validate-and-masked-input?rq=1)